# trouble to complete app about incoming call blocking

Tags: java, android

i wanted to make an app to block incoming call with the help of this blog http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2010/10/blocking-incoming-call-android.html  In this blog it only declares only the specific classes but there is no launcher activity like MainActivity.java . I imagine the launcher activity is look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PhoneCallReceiver abc=new PhoneCallReceiver();
    abc.onReceive(getApplicationContext(),getIntent());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

But it seems this way it does not work. I figure out there is several answer on this topics in stackoverflow. But i don't find which will be my launcher activity and how my app running background continuously .Please give me some link of complete tutorial on this or give me some direction.Thanks in advance:)

Comment: The blog is using Broadcast receivers for this. No activity is required really.

Comment: If there is no launcher activity how can i find my app in emulator/device ? @Namphibian

Comment: A broadcast receiver will get a notification that a event has occured you will then start a background service to handle the data. I have done this with my call recording software. The application will be a seperate part of this.